# exchange 2013 email address policy not applying after changes in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2013

In our exchange environment we have an email address policy to give two email addresses, a friendly alias that is firstname.lastname, and another one based on an employee ID. When I change their first or last name in Active directory the change is not being propagate to their email address like I would expect.

If I change it within ECP the change is immediate. The only way to get the change to come across from directly editing the account in Active Directory users and computers is to turn off email address policy for the account and then turn it back on.

I have automated tools making these first/last name changes and it would be nice to not have to turn off/on email address policy to get the change to create their new alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the online ECP you must edit the policy, save and then apply it. One thing I kept forgetting to do was the apply part.

Comment: In my automated tools I have it disable the email address policy on that account and then enable it again. This creates the new alias.